# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass, intermediate html file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, registration

I'm getting this error `` undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass `` `NoMethodError in Pages#registration` when trying to render errors partial on sign up. I made the actual sign up form as a partial and then render it as content of a tab for a different page, so now when I try to render the error message it go through the intermediate page first which cause the error, is there anyway to get around this issue, or is it necessary to make the sign up form as an actual view instead of a partial. I rendered the error partial from the new action partial.

this is the registration.html file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#customer_register">Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vendor_register">Vendor</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="customer_register">
      <%= render "customers/new", customer: @customer %>

      </div>
      <div id="vendor_register">
      <%= render "customers/new", vendor: @vendor %>  
      </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

and the create method of the controller

```
def create
        @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
        if @customer.save
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to Discount Now #{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}"
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            render 'pages/registration'
        end
    end
```

the registration file render the new action as content of the tab.

error message partial:

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

            <div class="panel panel-danger">


                <div class="panel-body">

                    <ul>

                        <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>

                            <li><%= msg %></li>

                        <% end %>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<% end %>
```

new partial code:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: customer  %>
    <%= form_for customer do |f| %>
            <div class= "form-group">
                <div class= "row reg_row">
                    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "col-sm-6 form-control", placeholder: "first name", required: true, autofocus: true %>
                    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "col-sm-6 form-control", placeholder: "first name", required: true, autofocus: true %>
                </div>
                <div class= "row reg_row">
                    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "col-sm-6 form-control", placeholder: "email", required: true, autofocus: true %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "col-sm-6 form-control", placeholder: "password", required: true, autofocus: true %>
                </div>
                <div class= "row button-margin">
                    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

                </div>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def index

    end

    def about

    end

    def faq

    end

    def contact

    end

    def registration

    end

    def login

    end

end
```

Would this code work if I add the newly initialized customer object  to the registration file when i rendered the new action?

so I edit the code to render the error partial from the new partial while passing in the customer variable that was create when the registration file render the new partial, so now the error become a name error in pages#registration, the error message read

```
undefined local variable or method `customer' for #<#<Class:0x007fa6497deb40>:0x007fa648e32268>
Did you mean?  customer_url
```

Comment: Try  `<%= render("customers/new", obj: @customer) %>`

Comment: Wait where you are rendering the errors partial in the main view page?

Comment: where should I include this line of code in ?

Comment: You said the the code belongs to an error partial. What its file name and where you are actually rendering it?

Comment: I rendered it in the new partial, but I'm just changed the code to render the error partial in the registration file now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message, we can conclude that your `obj` is set somewhere to `nil`. Otherwise, you would get `NameError: undefined local variable or method` error.

Make sure you have that `obj` local variable set appropriately. If it can be `nil`, then add an `if` check or use `try()` method.

```
<% if obj && obj.errors.any? %>

  # OR

<% if obj.try(:errors).try(:any?) %>

  # OR, if you are using Ruby 2.3 or later

<% if obj&.errors&.any? %>
```

Comment: actually the error also said `NoMethodError in Pages#registration`

Comment: Well, then add the `Pages#registration` action and the full error backtrace. So that we don't sit here and guess...

Comment: I have included registration file from the beginning actually and the the registration action in pages controller is an empty method cause it does nothing but being an intermediate page for the partial new action

Comment: That's an registration erb file, isn't it? Please include the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#customer_register">Customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vendor_register">Vendor</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="customer_register">
  <%= render("customers/new") %> # THIS IS NOT A PARTIAL

  </div>
  <div id="vendor_register">
  <%= render("vendors/new") %>   # THIS IS NOT A PARTIAL
  </div>
</div>
```

If it were a partial, you would need to do something like this.

`<%= render "customers/new", customer: @customer %>`

Then, within your `customer/new.html.erb`, you refer to everything as `customer` because that variable now exists. It's most likely that because you arent passing the model into the nested template partial, you get a `undefined method`errors' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: so I fixed it according to what you said, by passing customer object to the partial, but the error still persist, so I think the problem is passing the customer object to registration page and some how that object is set to nil.

Comment: Okay then do this. Instead of calling render within that controller, use 'redirect_to registrations_pages_path' (use 'rake routes' if you aren't sure what the path is. Then inside the 'registration' action, you can create a @customer if you have done so already.